# Macbook air screen is too bright even on the lowest setting

Tags: macbook-pro, screen, display

Is there a tweak, hack, or piece of software that can adjust the brightness of the MacBook Air's screen below the settings that MacOS X allows by default?

In low light the lowest brightness setting is too bright for me (and the setting after that is black so that doesn't work at all). :-)

Comment: Don't [cross-post](http://superuser.com/questions/280583/macbook-air-screen-is-too-bright-even-on-the-lowest-setting). Also, explain what's wrong with Flux and Nocturne?

Comment: Flux and nocturne don't do what I want, I don't want invertion I want a dimmer screen. Didn't mean to x-post, just found out about apple.stackexchange too late. Shades tho is perfection.

Comment: Had you bothered to open Nocturne preferences, you would have seen the *Invert screen* checkbox, and quite a few others, right at the top. Leave only *Adjust screen brightness*, and it does what you want. Flux is actually more sophisticated, not doing brightness, but changing the perceived [color temperature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_temperature) of your screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use and recommend [Shades](http://www.charcoaldesign.co.uk/shades) (free), which can darken the screen beyond the built-in brightness control.  If you really want to get it darker, use the built-in shortcut <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> to invert the screen colors (same command reverses the effect).

[Nocturne](http://www.blacktree.com/) (free) allows you to tweak some of the inversion settings.

Answer (score 0):

Supplemental answer; this question was cross-posted to Superuser and to avoid answer fragmentation I'll include the entirety of [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/280605/390541) there:

> I use [Flux](http://stereopsis.com/flux/) which helps me a lot at night. It gives you a somewhat lower brightness and the colors are adjusted according to the light you choose.