# What is the reason for the large minimum brightness of MacBook Air (or other devices)?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, screen

When I use my MacBook Air in darkness for various reasons (e.g. causal stargazing or working late in close quarters) the last brightness notch before "black" is way too bright for me.

There are add-on work-arounds (see for example [Macbook air screen is too bright even on the lowest setting](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/13728/143729)) so I'm not asking how to get lower brightness.

I'm wondering if there are some hardware issues when operating at very low brightness that should be avoided, or if it's just a question of difficulty to assure the customer display quality at very low brightness, or something else?

Comment: I don't know the specifics for your MacBook Air screen, but often brightness is controlled by turning off/on the backlight in very small intervals. The brain will perceive that as a constant light, but less bright. However if the intervals become too long, you'll start to experience the display as flickering. Therefore there's a limit as to how low brightness you can achieve with this method.

Comment: @jksoegaard OK that's an interesting theory. I should be able to look at it with a photodiode or phototransistor and oscilloscope, except I don't have those handy. However they may modulate the pulse width at constant period instead of varying the period. But that could also have limitations as well. I like this theory!

Comment: It is likely a log or linear scale and that is just what you get when computing the values

Comment: @William Volume is also *likely a log or linear scale* and it works great, going down to very low values before shutting off. I'd guess that Apple can implement whatever scale they decide is optimal for the user experience.

Comment: I noticed that my iMacs seem to dislike low brightnesses while my MacBooks are fine with it. They've all got LED backlighting, so I'm not sure what ths issue would be there.

Comment: @JMY1000 your leaving a comment to tell me you don't know the answer? I don't think that all displays that use LED backlighting necessarily use *the same* kind of backlighting, so a comparison to a desktop unit is not helpful.

Comment: @uhoh Correct, if I had the answer I'd leave an answer. Seems plausible, but just thought it might be an interesting observation, and potentially useful for someone who sees this question.

Comment: @JMY1000 The problem is not only that I find the display is just too bright for my comfort in a completely dark environment, I have complains from others nearby trying to sleep as well. That's the sentiment behind the (recently deleted) graphic https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiKd7.jpg It's nice to know that your laptops are not too bright for you when you work in darkness (that's what your comment says, correct?), but I'm not really doing an opinion pole here.

Comment: @uhoh I'm of the opinion that the graphic was confusing and distracting from the main point of the problem, which is to figure out why the brightness increments differently on different machines. That's why I left my comment: I know it's not an opinion poll, but understanding what hardware does what could be useful in discovering why that hardware does what it does.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried to split the last notch in 4 part, pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> ?

It allow you to have other three level before `black` screen. It will works also with audio.

Comment: FWIW On my MacBook Pro Retina, 15-inch, Early 2013, **⌃⇧F1** with just the first indicator position lit, and pressed three times, had no noticeable change, but it did from any of the other indicator positions. The same was true with **⌃⇧F2** with no indicator lit, other than the first press, I saw no noticeable change until the start of the second indicator being lit. So while this doesn't work for me on the lowest indicator position and may not work for some on the lowest indicator position, it's still a nice tip and worth a +1.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the interesting suggestion! On my circa-2012 MacBook Air it works *increasing above* the last full notch, but does not dim below it. I get four increments of identical brightness, then suddenly zero. I think this may be a strict hardware lower limit.